# Android on screen click

Tags: android

I have one image..which consists of two buttons in it. I don't want to use default button control rather i want to perform action on the buttons of image.

is there any way to  perform onclick on the buttons of image..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Button Widget. If you dont like the default look you can specify a custom Image for the Button with the Attribute:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

---

if you need different images for pressed/hovered you can make a custom Drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImageButton`

```
ImageButton yourButton; // Declare as class member
```

onCreate code:

```
yourButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);


yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
    // your code 
  }
});
```

The xml code is :

```
<ImageButton 
   android:background="@drawable/img_btn_bg"
   android:src="@drawable/img_to_show"></ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to split up the image and then u can use the code of havexz on each of the two images. Im not sure, but i dont think u can just give an Area of an image, which will react on Clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `GestureDetector` class. You should override the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` of the `ImageView` to call the `onTouchEvent(event)` of the `GestureDetector` and implement your own `OnSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event)` in the attached listener to get the coordinates of the tap using `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` methods to determine the coordinates of the click.

Also you should override the `onDown(MotionEvent event)` method of the listener to return `true`.

Not the most elegant solution perhaps, but it will do the job.